# whats the difference between call function inside statefulwidged and inside initState() in flutter

Tags: flutter

What's the difference between the call function inside the stateful widget directly and inside initState() in flutter? like the example below:

in data.dart:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() =>  [
  {"name" : "osama", "desc": "hello osama", "sal": 1000},
  {"name" : "ali", "desc": "hello ali", "sal": 800},
  {"name" : "ahmed", "desc": "hello ahmed", "sal": 600},
];
```

in main.dart

```
import 'package:column_app/data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Info(),));

class Info extends StatefulWidget {
  const Info({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Info> createState() => InfoState();
}

class  InfoState extends State<Info> {
  var info = getData();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: info.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Center(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(info[index]['name'].toString()),
                subtitle: Text(info[index]['desc'].toString()),
                leading: Text(info[index]['sal'].toString()),
              )
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
}
```

or this way:

```
import 'package:column_app/data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Info(),));

class Info extends StatefulWidget {
  const Info({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Info> createState() => InfoState();
}

class  InfoState extends State<Info> {
  var info;
@override
initState() {
  info = getData();
  super.initState();
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: info.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Center(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(info[index]['name'].toString()),
                subtitle: Text(info[index]['desc'].toString()),
                leading: Text(info[index]['sal'].toString()),
              )
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: From https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html: "Override this method to perform initialization that depends on the location at which this object was inserted into the tree (i.e., context) or on the widget used to configure this object (i.e., widget)."

Answer (score 0):

- in initState you could call functions and do actions when the class loaded for the first time , while inside the stateful widget directly you must not call any methods or any actions.
- you are only allowed to define the class members this is the only way to call a function there is to be for defining a class member .
- try to call a print function inside the stateful widget directly and it will give you compile time error.

Comment: give me an example to enforce me to use initState?

Comment: try to put this line of code inside the stateful widget directly and you will get an error that this line is putted in inexecutable place , the line : print("hello inside the stateful widget directly");

Comment: i know that, but it is not important and not a real example, I need a real example. and what is the different?